# Torquebox Backgroundable Method calls

Tags: neo4j, torquebox

I am using Torquebox to build a Rails application with an embedded Neo4j instance as the datastore. I've read multiple blogs that have said that Torquebox is a great for this because the Backgroundable method calls run in the same process (replacing delayed_job which doesn't work under jRuby anyway).

Unfortunately after playing around with it, this clearly isn't the case since the new thread keeps trying to start Neo4j and it fails.

After looking at the documentation, I did find this which confirms it:

> The message processors run in a separate ruby runtime from the application, which may be on a different machine if you have a cluster.

I'm new to Torquebox, so I'm not sure if people are just incorrect on this, or is there another way with Torquebox to do an asynchronous call that runs in the same process so it can interact with an embedded Neo4j data store?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with `Rails`/`Torquebox`, but are you creating a new `Neo4j` graph in each thread? If so, in `Neo4j`, only one connection can be made to the graph database in an embedded environment. If you host a `Neo4j` and use a `RESTful` client to call the DB you can have multiple clients.

Comment: You can spawn multiple threads and still hit Neo4j since in embedded mode it runs in the same process. Since Torquebox offers so much of that out of the box, I was hoping to leverage it instead of rolling my own.

Using the Server just isn't feasible for us due to the large number of writes we need to do which causes problems with the RESTful Server

Comment: What I meant was that if you are creating a new instance of the Embedded graph database class in each thread, you'll run into problems, as the Graph Database only allows one Object to connect to that database in an embedded environment. If you are creating a singleton object and passing it to each thread you should be safe.